# Why can't I insert/update data without locking the entire table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking, insert-update, database-deadlocks

I am trying to insert/update rows in a SQL Server table (depending on whether it exists or not). I am executing the SQL from multiple threads on multiple machines and I want to avoid getting duplicate key errors.

I have found many solutions online but all of them are causing transaction deadlocks. This is the general pattern I have been using:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET Data = @Data 
WHERE Key = @Key

IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO TestTable (Key, Data)
     VALUES (@Key, @Data)
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I have tried:

- `WITH XLOCK` instead of `UPDLOCK`
- `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` at the beginning with `UPDLOCK`
- `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` and no table hints

I have also tried the following pattern with all the combinations above:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE Key=@Key) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE TestTable
    SET Data = @Data 
    WHERE Key = @Key
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TestTable (Key, Data)
    VALUES (@Key, @Data)
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The only way I can get it to work without deadlocks is to use `WITH (TABLOCKX)`.

I am using SQL Server 2005, the SQL is generated at runtime and so it is not in a stored procedure and some of the tables use composite keys rather than primary keys but I can reproduce it on a table with an integer primary key.

The server logs look like this:

```
waiter id=processe35978 mode=RangeS-U requestType=wait
waiter-list
owner id=process2ae346b8 mode=RangeS-U
owner-list
keylock hobtid=72057594039566336 dbid=28 objectname=TestDb.dbo.TestTable indexname=PK_TestTable id=lock4f4fb980 mode=RangeS-U associatedObjectId=72057594039566336
waiter id=process2ae346b8 mode=RangeS-U requestType=wait
waiter-list
owner id=processe35978 mode=RangeS-U
owner-list
keylock hobtid=72057594039566336 dbid=28 objectname=TestDb.dbo.TestTable indexname=PK_TestTable id=lock2e8cbc00 mode=RangeS-U associatedObjectId=72057594039566336
```

The mode is obviously different depending on the table hint used (but the processes are always waiting for the mode they already own). I have seen RangeS-U, RangeX-X and U.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I have just tried this and unfortunately I still get the deadlocks executing with:
    UPDATE TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)

Comment: Are the deadlocks occurring with a single call or due to multithreading?

Comment: @Chris: Due to multithreading.

Comment: I believe it is to do with a server setting 'max degree of parallelism' which = 0 on the offending machine but 1 on another machine that is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this again today and found that I had been a bit of a numpty. I was actually running:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE Key=@Key) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE TestTable
    SET Data = @Data, Key = @Key -- This is the problem
    WHERE Key = @Key
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TestTable (Key, Data)
    VALUES (@Key, @Data)
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I was locking the key myself. Duh!

Answer (score 2):

How about doing your insert first with a join on the table to check for it's existence:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

WITH ToInsert AS(
     SELECT @Key AS Key, @Data AS Data
)
INSERT INTO TestTable (Key, Data)
SELECT ti.Key, ti.Data
FROM ToInsert ti
LEFT OUTER JOIN TestTable t
     ON t.Key = ti.Key
WHERE t.Key IS NULL

IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
     UPDATE TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
     SET Data = @Data 
     WHERE Key = @Key
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

That way your UPDATE statement is assured there always is a record present and your INSERT and INSERT-check is in the same atomic statement instead of being two separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your deadlock is on the index resource.

In the execution plan look for bookmark/key lookups and create a non-clustered index covering those fields - that way the 'read' of the data for the UPDATE will not clash with the 'write' of the INSERT.

Comment: Thanks @kev I appreciate this is a late response. I have checked the where clauses of the queries and they are all querying the primary key in the correct order - and using the indexes in the execution plan.